# Multiple References to the JQuery Library in a page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, master-pages

I have an ASP.NET application using a master page.  I am adding a reference to the JQuery library in the master page however there are some content pages and user controls that reference the JQuery library directly.  **Will I need to remove each reference from those pages or can I leave them in place even though I am adding a reference into the master page of the application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading jQuery with the Script Manager, it should load only once.

If you still want intellisense, you can use the following trick:

```
<% if (false) { %>
  <script src="....... script tag here
<% } %>
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I was doing, but your suggestion did give me the idea I used to solve my "backwards compatibility" problem. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should remove them, including the library twice has many side-effects, wiping out any plugins defined for example.  It'll load fine, but you'll start getting `.pluginMethod` is not defined, etc.

To avoid the headaches, only include them once, or [register the script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx) with the same key, and let ASP.Net do the include, and with the same key, it'll do so only once.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove them I'm afraid. Came across this issue myself and the javascript will break.

Comment: Yeah that what I was afraid of.  Not a terrible problem because the application has just started using features implemented in JQuery but now the site needs it to be a global reference.